# layer.average not showing as expected in keras plot_model

Tags: keras, tensorflow

My goal is to create a simple ensemble of three identical multi-output models (model0,model1,model2). Each model has two outputs named $a$ and $b$. The final ensemble should that have two outputs, by averaging the corresponding outputs of the three models.

$$ensemble.a = (model0.a + model1.a + model2.a)/3$$
$$ensemble.b = (model0.b + model1.b + model2.b)/3$$

A minimum working example of the code is the following. The function *build_model* creates a single model, and the function *build_ensemble* defines the ensemble.  Suffixes are added to layer names to avoid the error "*All layer names should be unique*".

```
import tensorflow as tf

def build_model(input_shape: tuple, suffix) -> tf.keras.Model:
    input_layer = tf.keras.layers.Input(input_shape, name='model_input'+suffix)
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=50, name='dense'+suffix),
    ], name='base_estimator')
    model = model(input_layer)
    model_a = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, name='out_a'+suffix)(model)
    model_b = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1, name='out_b'+suffix)(model)
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=[model_a, model_b], name='model_output'+suffix)
    return model

def build_ensemble(input_shape: tuple) -> tf.keras.Model:
    input_layer = tf.keras.layers.Input(input_shape, name='ensemble_input')
    model1 = build_model(input_shape,suffix="_0")
    model2 = build_model(input_shape,suffix="_1")
    model3 = build_model(input_shape,suffix="_2")
    y1_a, y1_b = model1(input_layer)
    y2_a,y2_b = model2(input_layer)
    y3_a,y3_b = model3(input_layer)
    out_a = tf.keras.layers.average([y1_a, y2_a,y3_a],name="out_a")
    out_b = tf.keras.layers.average([y1_b, y2_b,y3_b],name="out_b")
    ensemble_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=[out_a,out_b],name='ensemble_output')
    return ensemble_model


m = build_ensemble((20,))
tf.keras.utils.plot_model(m,"test.png",expand_nested=True)
```

The problem is that the plot created by tf.keras.utils.plot_model is not the expected. Specifically, the plotted architecture uses only the second output from each model. In the following figure, I have crossed out wrong connections with red and have added with green the connections that should be there instead.

[image]

So according, to the diagram, the computation of ensemble.a seems to be wrong (it uses $b$ instead of $a$):

$$ensemble.a = (model0.b + model1.b + model2.b)/3$$
$$ensemble.b = (model0.b + model1.b + model2.b)/3$$

Question: Is there a mistake in my architecture that I should correct or is this a bug in the plotting library? More importantly, am I actually computing the desired output?

Note: The ensembling approach using layers.average is explained in the official guide: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/functional

Comment: I'd suggest opening an issue on Tensorflow's [Issues](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues) page. I tried `print(m.summary())` and it looked like `out_a` is receiving the right inputs from each `model_output_i[0][0]`. There's a related [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/42101). I also tried upgrading to 2.10.0 and replacing the `average` layer with a `concatenate` layer and it returned the same plot. Disclaimer: I haven't built a model like this before, but I think their Issues page is good if you don't get a response here.